# flutter run on Mac M1

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

> when I run my app project appear error I didn't understand the problem so please anyone has any solution and help me. I run on terminal (flutter run --verbose) and appear

```
    #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:674:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1140:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:94:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: have  you tried? to run pod install inside the path of flutter in ios.

Comment: @ArbiterChil,  yes and appear this error 'Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215c76b90) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x105fe42c8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[43403]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x215c76be0) and /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x105fe4318). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.'